# Touch event in MapView in android

Tags: android, google-maps

hi i am using a mapview in my application.it showing correctly but the problem is when i touch map view its not moving if a user want to see nearby location he cant move to that location.you can say that mapview is not responding to touchevent in my layout.here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50px" 
    android:autoLink="web"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/department"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80px" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/latitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/zoomin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="ZoomIn"/>
<Button

android:id="@+id/zoomout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Zoom Out"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:apiKey="0PmsmqKFKflNmHXD2fwG_vPWnR2gA-YB2QVlIQA"
                 android:layout_weight="2"
                 />

</LinearLayout>
```

moving to different location when any view is any location is touched by default can any one please tell why its not moving and what should i do so that on touch event it will move.

Comment: mapview changed by default when we change in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly its that when you try to move around the map its not doing anything.. It might help to add theese two lines inside your XML

```
android:enabled="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

It should look like this inside your snippet:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:apiKey="0PmsmqKFKflNmHXD2fwG_vPWnR2gA-YB2QVlIQA"
                 android:layout_weight="2"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 />
```

So try add the two lines inside your XML at the MapView object and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome tutorial here http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android?page=1