# How to capture map touch event - not map overlay touch event

Tags: android, maps

I have an Android real estate map app. I have small overlays that show the price of properties.  When an overlay is clicked, I show a dialog with some property info. On my new HTC phone, when I click anywhere else on the map, the dialog closes - as I want. 
On some phones the dialog does not close, and the user has to hit the back key to get rid of the dialog.

How can I get a reference to that dialog and dismiss it on on map touch?

I have thoroughly searched this on Stack Overflow and found some answers, but they haven't worked for me.  Usually, they are showing the touch event for overlays.  I need the touch event for the map and to check if there is any open dialog and dismiss it (it is from another class as it was created when a map overlay was clicked).

My main activity extends `MapActivity`.

Comment: i found this [Touch event in MapView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778196/touch-event-in-mapview-in-android)

Comment: What type of dialog are you showing when user taps. Better to post that part of code, so we can try to find what's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  For now, I am just trying to capture the onclick event of the user touching the map.  I've even added implements OnClickListener to the mapactivity.  On click of overlays works easily.  But, I can't seem to capture just touching the map.

Comment: Also, I do have android1:clickable="true"
        android1:enabled="true" > on the xml mapview